# Left (right) derived functor construction: motivation

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homology-cohomology, functors, derived-functors

Suppose that $\mathcal{A}$ is a category with enough projective-injective. The construction of left or right derived functors I know is: for an object $A \in \mathcal{A}$ take a projective (resp. injective) resolution $P^{\bullet}$ of $A$, i.e., $P^{\bullet} \to A$ and apply the functor $F$ and then take homology or cohomology in each degree.

In the special case of the category of $R$-modules, taking $B \in \mathrm{Mod}_R$ we have $\mathrm{Hom}(B,\bullet)$ or $\mathrm{Hom}(\bullet,B)$ from which we can construct $\mathrm{Ext}_R^i(B,\bullet)$ or $\mathrm{Ext}_R^i(\bullet,B)$. I have trouble understanding the following:

If I want to construct $\mathrm{Ext}_R^i(B,A)$, since $\mathrm{Hom}(B,\bullet)$ is left exact, I take a injective resolution of $A$, and then $\mathrm{Hom}(B,\bullet)$ to create $\mathrm{Ext}_R^i(A,B)$.

On the other side the controvariant functor $\mathrm{Hom}(\bullet,B)$ requires me to take a projective resolution of $A$ and do it similarly.

So my question is the following: is there any particular reason to do so? It seems to me that even if $\mathrm{Hom}(\bullet,B)$ is left exact, I could take an injective resolution $Q^{\bullet}$ of $A$, take $\mathrm{Hom}(\bullet,B)$, obtaining $\cdots \to \mathrm{Hom}(Q_n,B) \to \cdots \to \mathrm{Hom}(Q_0,B) \to 0$? Is this not allowed? Is the exactness of the contravariant functor $\mathrm{Hom}(\bullet,B)$ hidden somewhere? Is there a problem on “where to start”?

Any help or clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: You can compute $\text{Ext}^{\bullet}(A, B)$ using either a projective resolution of $A$ or an injective resolution of $B$, and which one ends up being easier to find or work with is situational. For example, there is a particular Ext which computes group cohomology and there picking a specific projective resolution of $A$ called the bar resolution tells you how to compute group cohomology in terms of cocycles. On the other hand categories of sheaves often fail to have enough projectives and so there one needs injective resolutions.

Comment: Thanks for the remark. I feel like this doesn’t really answer my question. My question was, are there any inconsistency using the second construction? I.e taking Hom(,B) on a injective resolution as in the question? Does it make sense? Is this path defining an other functor?

Comment: I don't understand what your question is then. Are you asking whether taking projective resolutions vs. injective resolutions defines the same Ext functor? (It does.) Or something else?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Could you add a reference of the cited "aking projective resolutions vs. injective resolutions defines the same Ext functor? (It does.) "

Comment: You can check the citation on Wikipedia, it refers to Theorem 2.7.6 in Weibel: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_functor#cite_note-2